# For Loop only prints the first value

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to web scrape stock data using a for loop on a list of five stocks. The problem is only the first value is returned five times. I have tried appending to a list but it still doesn't work, although clearly I am not appending correctly. On the website, I want to get the data for Operating Cash which comes in the form of 14B or 1B for example, which is why I have removed the B and multiplied that number to get a raw value. Here is my code:

```
import requests
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
stocks = ['AMC','AMD','PFE','AAPL', 'NVDA']
finished_list = []
for stock in stocks:
    url = f'https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/{stock}/financials/cash-flow'
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
    operating_cash = soup.findAll('div', class_ = "cell__content")[134].text
    finished_list.append(operating_cash)
    if 'B' in operating_cash:
        cash1 = operating_cash.replace('B','')
        if '(' in cash1:
            cash2 = cash1.replace('(','-')
        if ')' in cash2:
            cash3 = cash2.replace(')','')
            cash3 = float(cash3)
            print(cash3*1000000000)
        else:
            cash1 = float(cash1)
            print(cash1 * 1000000000)
```

The current output is -1060000000.0 five times in a row which is the correct value for operating cash for AMC but not for the other four. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `if` conditions for `str.replace()`. Instead, do all your replacements in one line like so:

```
for stock in stocks:
    url = f'https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/{stock}/financials/cash-flow'
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
    operating_cash = soup.findAll('div', class_ = "cell__content")[134].text
    finished_list.append(operating_cash)
    cash = float(operating_cash.replace('B','').replace('(','-').replace(')',''))
    print(cash*1000000000)

-1060000000.0
1070000000.0000001
14400000000.0
80670000000.0
5820000000.0
```